# Total amount of sessions per user for oracle cluster of 4 nodes

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

We have Oracle 11g Enterprise 64bit and it is a cluster of 4 nodes.
There is a user with limit of 96 sessions_per_user. We thought that the total limit of sessions for this user is 4 nodes * 96 = 384 sessions. But the reality is no more than something about 180 sessions. After approximately 180 sessions being opened we get erros:

> ORA-12850: Could not allocate slaves on all specified instances: 4
>   needed, 3 allocated    ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query
>   server P004, instance 3599
>   ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous
>   SESSIONS_PER_USER limit

The question is why the total limit is only 180 sessions? Why is it not 4*96?

We would greatly appreciate your answer.

Comment: I think your question is more for DBA's. Ask here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't find it documented, a quick test implies you are correct that the maximum total number of sessions is equal to SESSIONS_PER_USER * Number of Nodes.  However, that will only be true if the sessions are balanced evenly across the nodes.  Each instance still enforces that limit.

Check the service you are connecting to, and if that service is available on all nodes.  Run these commands to look at the preferred nodes and the actual running nodes.  It's possible that there was a failure, a service migrated to one node, and never migrated back.

```
# Preferred nodes:
srvctl config service -d $your_db_name
# Running nodes:
srvctl status service -d $your_db_name
```

Or possibly the connections are hard-wired to a specific instance.  This is usually a mistake, but sometimes it is necessary for things like running the PL/SQL debuggers.  Run this query to see where your parallel sessions are spawning:

```
select inst_id ,gv$session.* from gv$session;
```

Also check the parameter PARALLEL_FORCE_LOCAL and make sure it is not set to true:

```
select value from gv$parameter where name = 'parallel_force_local';
```

Or perhaps there's an issue with counting the number of sessions.  The number of sessions is frequently more than the requested degree of parallelism.  For example, if the query sorts or hashes Oracle will double the number of parallel sessions, one set to produce the rows and one set to consume the rows.  Are you sure of the number of parallel sessions being requested?

Also, in my tests, when I ran a parallel query without enough SESSIONS_PER_USER, it simply downgraded my query.  I'm not sure why your database is throwing an error.  (Perhaps you've got parallel queuing and a timeout set?)

Lastly, it looks like you are using an extremely high degree of parallelism.  Are you sure that you need hundreds of parallel processes?

Chances are there are a lot of other potential issues I haven't thought of.  Parallelism and RAC are complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your early reply. PARALLEL_FORCE_LOCAL is really set to true. So we wrote DBAs our request to change this settings (we have not enougth permissions to do it by ourselves).